# GWT retrieve XML data on server

Tags: java, xml, gwt

I try to retrieve  XML data from an external server and to display informations on my GWT application.

The problem is that I don't succeed to display the xml informations.

My Java code :

```
protected void retrieveXmlDataTop(final VerticalPanel c) {

    url = "http://www.myapifilms.com/imdb/top?format=XML&start=1&end=25&data=S";

    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,URL.encode(url));

    try
    {
        builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                // Couldn't connect to server (could be timeout, SOP
                // violation, etc.)
                Window.alert("Couldn't retrieve XML");

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {

                if (200 == response.getStatusCode())
                {
                    // Process the response in response.getText()
                    parseMessage(c , response.getText());
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle the error. Can get the status text from
                    // response.getStatusText()
                    //Window.alert("Error: " + response.getStatusText());
                    Label error = new Label("Error");
                    c.add(error);
                }
            }


        });
    }
    catch (RequestException e)
    {
        // Couldn't connect to server
        Window.alert("Couldn't connect to server to retrieve the XML: \n");
    }
}

private void parseMessage(final VerticalPanel c, String messageXml)
{
    try
    {
        // parse the XML document into a DOM
        Document messageDom = XMLParser.parse(messageXml);

        String tag1Value = messageDom.getElementsByTagName("ranking").item(0)
                .getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        String tag2Value = messageDom.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0)
                .getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

        //Window.alert("Ranking Value: " + tag1Value + "\n" + "Title Value: " + tag2Value);
        Label result = new Label("Ranking Value: " + tag1Value + "\n" + "Title Value: " + tag2Value);
        c.add(result);

    }
    catch (DOMException e)
    {
        Window.alert("Could not parse XML document.");
    }
}
```

And my xml page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<movies>
    <movie>
        <idIMDB>tt0111161</idIMDB>
        <ranking>1</ranking>
        <rating>9.2</rating>
        <title>The Shawshank Redemption</title>
        <urlPoster>http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_SX34_CR0,0,34,50_AL_.jpg</urlPoster>
        <year>1994</year>
    </movie>
</movies>
```

I obtain always the message "Error".

Comment: Which status code do you receive from the server?

Comment: I want to receive all the information of the XML code

Comment: Yes, I understand, but what is the actual status code that you receive, i.e. what does `response.getStatusCode()` return?

Comment: response.getStatusCpde() = 0 and if I put 0 at the place of 200, I enter in the condition but after I have the Windows alert : **Window.alert("Could not parse XML document.");** in my function parseMessage.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the answer, because of the [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). (Statuscode 0 means is the hint)

If you open the dev-tools of your browser, you may see the request and the response and may be a warning about security concerns of the request.

If you want to get an answer fron the server your frontend must be delivered from the same origin as the API or the API server and the browser needs to be [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) compliant.

Comment: "or the API needs to be CORS compliant" - and the browser too, if the browser doesn't support CORS, the request still won't be sent.

Comment: Of course, just need to be sure you aren't working on an 'enterprise' or internal app where you can't use real browsers ;).

Comment: I really like to work on "enterprise" software. There are more problems to solve than even could exist with real browser. ;)